# Javascript isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this javascript the components drag function isn't working. The problem occurs only in my site. In SO's code snippet it works. 
You can see the test here: https://screensos.github.io/Windowing.js/test.html
Anyone know why this happens ?

```js
var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos ;
    y_elem = y_pos;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
var draggables = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable-element');
for(var i = 0; i < draggables.length; i++){
  draggables[i].onmousedown = function () {
      _drag_init(this);
      return false;
  };
}

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

```css
body {padding:10px}

.draggable-element {
  width:125px;
  height:125px;
  background-color:#666;
  color:white;
  padding:10px 12px;
  cursor:move;
  position:relative; /* important (all position that's not `static`) */
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance. You can try it locally, by downloading the source from here: https://github.com/ScreensOS/Windowing.js

**Update**: The error was the javascript tag placed in a wrong position. Instead of after the head tag, now placed before the end of body tag.

Comment: `Javascript isn't working`. What is the question? Please check your console for errors.

Comment: Contact github. They may restrict it

Comment: The problem isn't on GitHub. Locally is the same.

Comment: @Ionut, my question is in the title, if not the editor would change it, not? The console is blank.

Comment: Both locally and in the https://screensos.github.io/Windowing.js/test.html the javascript isn't working.

Comment: @Plasmmer, `Javascript isn't working` is not a question. What editor are you talking about? You are the only one who knows what you want to ask. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What would be a good question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the place you load you script. Change

```
<html><head>
<title>Drag</title>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

to

```
<html><head>
<title>Drag</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<div class="draggable-element">Gadget!<div style="width:20px;height:100%;background:#000;position:absolute;top:0;right:-25px"></div></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your script tries to get the `draggable-element` DOM elements before the DOM is loaded.

Solutions:
Place `<script src="script.js"></script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag to delay loading of the script until the elements are loaded into the DOM.

Alternatively you can use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //code here
});
```

in your script.js, to execute the script after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: This question is usefull, too. Thanks.